# error: cannot find -lrt clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)？

Tags: android-ndk, openmp

I want to use openMP in android ndk .I add code in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

but It makes an error `C:/WORK/android-ndk-r13b/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -lrt clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`when execute `ndk-build`
'

Answer (score 0):

Clang support for OpenMP in the NDK is still a work in progress: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/9